# javascript - difference between this and var in class object

Tags: javascript

Would like to know what is the difference between variable test1 and test2 in the following code.

```
function myClass(){
var test1 = 'abc';
this.test2 = 'def';

this.Method1 = function(){
    someObj(this.success);
}

this.success = function(){
    console.log(test1); //able to output value
    console.log(this.test2); //unable to get the output
            console.log(test2); //unable to get the output
}
}
```

Edit: to make more precise, I was trying to access to the variable from an inner function. I couldn't access to the test2 variable, but able to extract the value from test1.

Comment: *"...what is the difference between variable test1 and test2..."* Well, for a start, `test2` isn't a variable. :-) (See thefourtheye's answer for details...)

Comment: For difference between variables and properties, have a look at [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 4):

1. `test1` is a variable which is local to the `myClass` function. It cannot be accessed outside.
2. `test2` is a property of the current object on which `myClass` is invoked.

Based on the fact that function name has `Class` in it, I assume that it is a constructor function. So, `test2` will be set on the newly constructed object.

Answer (score 0):

[**Functions and function scope (MDN)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

It's all about **scope**. There's a great example and explanation here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

JavaScript really only has 2 types, **functional** and **global**.

`this.test2` *in this case* is the same as `window.test2`.

> The **this** keyword does not refer to the currently executing function, so you must refer to Function objects by name, even within the function body.

`var test1` will only be defined within your function `myClass`

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.